# Using neutral wire from outlet for smart switch

Tags: smart-switch

[image]
I have a 2 gang switch/outlet located in my garage and looking to replace both the outlet with an outlet that includes USB ports and the switch with a smart switch that requires neutral. The switch controls two exterior light fixtures outside of the garage. When I opened up the box, I found a couple pigtails with the wiring shown in the diagram (there is a ground wire from the outlet not shown in the diagram). I checked the wires with a non contact volt tester to determine the hot wires. I don't know if there are other outlets connected to the outlet in this box. Trying to figure out if (1) do I just use the same layout when replacing the outlet and (2) can I add a pigtail for neutral for the smart switch and if so, where?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This really doesn't make sense to me. (a) 3-wire cables typically used for MWBC (I don't think that's applicable here), 3-way switches (not applicable) and switch loops (very likely for cable 1, but not for cable 2). Especially strange is white and black that appear *together* on the receptacle - is that actually the case? White on a receptacle hot would be very unusual.

Comment: Only if the switch and outlet are on the same circuit(one single breaker for both).

Comment: How many circuit breakers do you have to turn off to fully de-energize this box?  Is it a funny wide breaker with apparent handle-ties?  Are the breakers next to each other?  Also your drawing around switch 2 is probably incorrect.  Pics would be good. If the pic is too large, load it up in any image program, "Save As ... JPEG... Quality 3" (really), and it should shrink greatly without harming resolution.

Comment: Assuming that the switch doesn't control the outlet and that you're only dealing with **ONE** circuit then there should be a neutral in that box already. Yes, pig-tail the neutral to both the new outlet and switch per the instructions.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica just one breaker to turn off this box.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact yes that’s how it is wired. Here is the photo. You can kind of see the white and black going to the same location. One is on the screw and the other through the back connect.  Updated post with the actual photo.

Comment: A picture of the other side of the receptacle, or better yet the back, would help.

Comment: Do you have any idea where the two cables go?  The way it's drawn, cable 1 looks to be bringing a hot and neutral to the outlet, and returning a switched hot.  But cable 2 makes no sense.  As shown, all three wires are hot and there's no neutral.  If that cable is not connected to anything, and the black and white are tied together at the other end, then the circuit would work.  You could simplify things by eliminating that cable.  It would sure be nice to know what's at the other end of it.

Comment: @Mark I don't know there the wires go. I think I'll try to map it out with a tone generator this weekend and take some more pics. Thanks.

Comment: If it was me I'd start by opening up the boxes that the two lights controlled by the switch are in.  One of them is probably the other end of cable 1.  It should also contain a cable bringing power into that box, and may also contain a third cable taking switched power to the second light.  It would be helpful to take pictures inside both boxes and add them to your question.

Comment: @Mark Added additional photos. Was not able to test with a tone generator yet. The single breaker switch also controls at least a couple other outlets in the garage. I was hoping not to have to open up the exterior fixtures but I might have to. FWIW, the home was built in the late 1980s.

Comment: This just does not make any sense at all. It would be **really helpful** to see what is at the other end of # 1 and # 2. But that's probably not so easy. Next best would be to identify which wire(s) are always hot - but the usual way to do that is to temporarily disconnect things, and that is highly problematic with the backstabs (which may or may not be working, so may actually be hiding some issues and/or by *not* working making things not blow up/short out). Ugh.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact from the perspective of working/not working, the light switch and outlet have always functioned for the past 30+ years my parents have been at this house and this box has never had service. That’s not to say that nothing is wrong with it but we haven’t experienced a problem. The impetus to open this was to change out for more features with newer receptacles / switch. I may have to start looking at the outside fixtures…